# PHP Anonymous functions: undefined variable

Tags: php, wordpress, php-5.3

I'm having these two WordPress functions:

```
$wpb_set_post_views = function($postID) {
    $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
};

add_action( 'wp_head', function ($post_id) {
    if ( !is_single() ) return;
    if ( empty ( $post_id) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }
    $wpb_set_post_views($post_id);
});
```

But the page return `Notice: Undefined variable: wpb_set_post_views` for the last line.

Comment: After `function ($post_id)` you need to add `use (wpb_set_post_views)`. The variable is out of scope.

Comment: @Andrew Did you mean `use ($wpb_set_post_views)` ?

Comment: Yes, my bad, forgot the `$`.

Comment: Well do you really need this to be an anonymous function?

Comment: Have you found the answer to your question yet?

Answer (score 10):

When dealing with Closures in PHP you need to ensure that any out of scope variable is put into the Closure scope. This is unlike JavaScript where closures have access to variables declared in a PHP scope.

Your anonymous function should be as follows

```
function() use ($variableNeeded) { }
```

You will then have access to that variable.

It is important to keep in mind that this is a pass by value scenario, so any changes to that variable will not be reflected outside the closure, so you would need to pass by reference to make changes.

```
function() use (&$variableNeeded) { }
```

Comment: There's really no need to pass it in by reference.

Comment: In this example, maybe not, but if you need the value change to be reflected outside the closure, you need to pass by reference. Calling closures is the same as calling any other function, so you will pass by value.

Answer (score 0):

Use global keyword to access the outside variables in a function.

So your code will be

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function ($post_id) {
    if ( !is_single() ) return;
    if ( empty ( $post_id) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }
    global $wpb_set_post_views;
    $wpb_set_post_views($post_id);
});
```

Or

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function ($post_id) {
        if ( !is_single() ) return;
        if ( empty ( $post_id) ) {
            global $post;
            $post_id = $post->ID;
        }
        $wpb_set_post_views = $GLOBALS['wpb_set_post_views'];
        $wpb_set_post_views($post_id);
    });
```

Please refer http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Global is really no the answer here.

Comment: Global is so 2008, do not use